# Dimmer switch buzzing

Tags: electrical, lighting, dimmer-switch

I have triple dimmer switch that switches different areas. One of the dimmers is buzzing. I have tried different lamps including LEDs, and it makes no difference. I have changed the dimmer unit and it makes no difference.

Anyone know why it continues to buzz and is there any way to stop it other than changing from dimmer to normal switches?

Comment: If it buzzes with all bulb types it's probably failing or a bad design. I'd try a better dimmer switch rather than eliminating the dimming option.

Comment: What brand did you install?

Comment: Most dimmers have some coils (i.e. magnetic) and these can "buzz" which is very annoying.  If it's intolerable your best option is to replace the noisy unit.

Comment: You may want to inspect the wire connections to ensure they are securely attached to the dimmer. I had a similar issue and while I had an electrician over for something else I had them take a look and it turned out that the wires just weren't secure enough.

Comment: I agree with @micah Montoya it may be arcing since you have changed lamp styles. Although I would have expected you to find a loose connection when replacing the unit. Could it be one of the other switches or a splice?

Comment: What make and model are the dimmers and lamps in question?

Comment: Is this the light that is buzzing or the switch where you flip it on that is buzzing?

Answer (score 1):

Buzzing is usually because something is physically loose inside, and is being vibrated by the electro-magnetic force from the internal wires.  This gets worse with dimming, because triac dimmers make a very bizarre waveform that makes insane amounts of harmonic distortion, and it may resonate better at 180 or 300Hz or 420Hz than 60Hz. You could crack it open and try to rectify that, but altering a UL-listed device would void that UL listing, so you couldn't legally put it back in the wall.

Comment: *rectify that* - then you have DC, LEDs are happy (unless the polarity is wrong) :-)

Comment: @manassehkatz Naked LED emitters enjoy DC.  With screw-in bulb replacement tech with a driver circuit and other stuff too, anything could happen -- some devices rely on that zero crossing to do useful things like stop current flow.  (in fact triac dimmers do that very thing).  Mid-voltage DC is Mr. Hyde - when it starts arcing, it cannot be bargained with, cannot be reasoned with, it does not know pity or remorse or fear...  I would not inflict it on a random AC device.

Answer (score 1):

The bottom line is that this technology is changing faster than Lutron and other dimmer companies can keep up with it. I've had several instances where someone installed a dimmer with an LED setup that produced some weird results, i.e. lights pulsing, humming, buzzing, etc. In one instance I had the light manufacturer and the Lutron tech on a conference call and the Lutron guy admitted they don't know what dimmer works with that light because they hadn't tested it yet.
The point is they are not all compatible. You have to start with the light and then work backward with the light manufacturer to find compatible dimmers. They will know - or at least they should.
Lastly, make sure all of your lights on the dimmer are the same. If you have 3 different types of lights on one dimmer the probability of incompatibility skyrockets.